# haskell -- odd ambiguous type variable error message for code in "where" statement with TypeFamilies extension

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, ambiguity

Does anyone know why this code fails?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction,
             TypeFamilies #-}

module Test where

asExprTyp :: Expr γ =>
    γ α
    -> α
    -> γ α
asExprTyp x _ = x

int = undefined :: Integer

class Expr γ where
    a :: γ α

-- this works fine
b = a `asExprTyp` int

-- this fails
mcode = do
    return ()
    where b = a `asExprTyp` int
```

The error is as follows,

```
Test.hs:23:15:
    Ambiguous type variable `γ0' in the constraint:
    (Expr γ0) arising from a use of `a'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the first argument of `asExprTyp', namely `a'
    In the expression: a `asExprTyp` int
    In an equation for `b': b = a `asExprTyp` int
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  What type do you expect `b` to have in the failing expression?

Comment: @JohnL: `b :: Expr γ => γ Integer`

Comment: @mergeconflict: that is perfectly reasonable.  I was thinking of γ as an associated type, which it definitely isn't.

Comment: @JohnL, the same type as the working sample??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what ghc complains about either. I thought it might be because it's trying to give the local binding a monomorphic type, but adding `NoMonoLocalBinds` to the language pragma didn't change anything.

However, the code compiles as is with a recent HEAD (7.3.20111026), together with the fact that it compiles without TypeFamilies enabled, that supports the bug hypothesis.

If it's a real problem you have to solve: adding type signatures makes ghc happy.

Comment: yes, seemed like a bug. Thanks for checking in with head... I don't keep check-outs in my sandbox because the build size is 2 gb.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is somewhat over my head since I've never used type families in Haskell.  However, your example isn't actually using type families either, so I thought I'd see what happens when I remove the `TypeFamilies` language extension from the `LANGUAGE` pragma.  Turns out: it compiles just fine then! :)

So it could very well be a GHC bug.

That being said, I poked at it a bit and noticed that the following compiles happily with `TypeFamilies` enabled:

```
mcode = do
            b
            return ()
        where b = a `asExprTyp` int
```

This is probably nonsensical, since its inferred type is `mcode :: (Expr m, Monad m) => m ()`, rather than just `mcode :: Monad m => m ()`, but my point is that GHC seems happy only when `a`'s type is tied in some way to `mcode`'s type.

Not sure if this is helpful, but it definitely piqued my curiosity!